# How to set HTML content in the ElementRef (nativeEelement)?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I want to set the content of HTML element with directive.

```
export class AdvertisementDirective {

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    el.nativeElement.style.background = 'yellow';
    el.nativeElement.content = '<p>Hello World<p>';
  }

}
```

But it does not work and doesn't give any error.

The idea behind doing this is to have Ad code in the directive and set it wherever I used directive attribute. The code for advertisement contains `JavaScript` and HTML code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

DOM Manipulations via directly changing properties on the `nativeElement` is not considered as a good practice. It's also not going to work in some cases like Web Workers and Server Side Rendering using Angular Universal.

A safer way of doing this is using **[`Renderer2`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)**.

```
import { ..., AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, Renderer2, ... } from '@angular/core';
...
export class AdvertisementDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('templateRefName') el: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'background', 'yellow');
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', '<p>Hello World<p>');
  }

}
```

And in template:

```
<div #templateRefName></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think it works to set `script` also?

Comment: I haven't tried that. But I don't think it would. To avoid XSS, Angular would block/strip the content to make it safe. Not completely sure though. Please give it a try on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular)

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing your nativeElement manipulation inside ngAfterViewInit? I once read that doing this inside ngOnInit could result the element being undefined. Not sure if that's only true for components.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've updated the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed it with the following:

```
el.nativeElement.innerHTML = '<p>Hello World<p>';
```

I realized the `nativeElement` should accept all the `JavaScript` methods as it is native HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

Appending text can also be achieved by using **createText** property of renderer2 object.

```
    import {ElementRef, ViewChild, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';


export class AdvertisementDirective {

  @ViewChild('templateRefName') el: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

   const text = this.renderer.createText('Hello World'); // <-- TO Be Noted
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, text);

  }

}
```